# Why is the scene duplicating then saying loading and not loading and how to do fix it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I press the play button the scene in the hierarchy duplicates then they switch between one saying "is loading" and the other saying "is not loading". This causes the buttons not to work.

I check that the button presses were on the Editor and Runtime option. And I made sure that the code worked although it is relativly simple. Here is the code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class UI_Manager : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start() => SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
    
    public void UI_Start() => SceneManager.LoadScene(0);

    public void UI_Quit() => Application.Quit();
}
```

Scene 0 is the Main Menu scene and Scene 1 is the actual game.

Comment: You say 1 and 2 but load 0 and 1. Which scenes contain the UI_Manager? How is UI_Start` called?

Comment: Start will run almost immediately and just load scene 1.  The other 2 become irrelevant because it will have changed scenes and this is gone

Comment: Sounds to me like the `void Start() => SceneManager.LoadScene(1);` is causing an infinite scene loading loop .. you constantly keep loading that scene which in the editor displays the one scene as being loading .. then as soon as this finishes this scene is unloaded and you load the same scene again...

Comment: @derHugo So I don't need the `void start`
Edit: I removed the void start and that worked. Thank you!!